# Equations for a 2D Gaussian Distribution on Grids

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, modeling, simulation

I'm simulating possible location data on grids which looks like the example figure below: [image]

S1 is the center that has the highest possibility of being chosen (e.g., 95%). The possibility of a cell being chosen near S1 decreases with its distance to S1: The farther a cell is from S1, the less likely it will be chosen. Therefore, the possibility of a cell being chosen is: S1 > S2 > S2' > S3 > S3' > S3'' . And all possibilities added up will be 1.

I think the distribution follows a discrete 2D Gaussian distribution. I know Gaussian is supposed to be continuous only, so there may be another term for it. I wonder if anyone have a suggestion on what equation I could write for this data simulation?

Comment: You need to know the parameters of this Gaussian distribution: what exactly are its mean location and covariance matrix?

Comment: My question is more about the equation itself instead of the exact parameter values. Is there a particular equation you are thinking about?

Comment: I was thinking about each cell as a discrete point, so a typical Gaussian distribution that is only used to describe probabilities for continuous variables may not fit. Please let me know if you have other thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Just to answer your question. I think the mean location in S1 as in most of the cases this location would be chosen. I'm not too sure about the covariance matrix if you were asking about the exact values. I will need to define it later when I implement the algorithms.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without specifying those parameters.

Comment: It's weird. I'm just asking for an equation. I'm confused why specific values matter that much.

Comment: Because there is no closed form formula and the complexity of the algorithm depends on those details.